# Should we forget fusion and focus on geothermal power?

Tags: power, fusion

Firstly I can say that I would love us to come up with a sustainable fusion solution.  However with the latest estimates being 2050 at the earliest for an effective fusion solution and the planets energy needs growing by the year should we not be looking at alternatives?

I understand that in the EU alone we are spending billions of Euro's on an experimental fusion reactor.

We sit on top of a thin crust which is in turn on top of a mantle with abundant heat.  Should we not be investing serious money into tapping into this heat source as a long term, sustainable solution to the planet's energy needs?

How far could we get if the money used for fusion was diverted to geothermal drilling and research?

Comment: Some of my 2 cents: A good answer for this question should include the fact that the Earth's core produces 30 TW of power sustainably versus the 15 TW needed to power society.  Temperature is a function of depth, so assumption of drilling tech limits max theoretical thermal efficiency, so assumptions about technology may limit the sustainable geothermal power to less that we use now.  Or you suggest using it non-sustainably like a fossil fuel.  Your choice.

Comment: @Zassounotsukushi: This is not needed for a good answer, because the "unsustainable" use of geothermal energy is only unsustainable to the extent that it cools the entire Earth! The time scale for us to do that from even the most non-sustainable exploitation is measured in geological time.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is a political one, not a physical one.  An energy portfolio, just like an investment one, is strongest when it is diversified.  Scientific breakthroughs, just like the stock market, are hard to predict.

Comment: @RonMaimon Point granted in the sense that fossil fuels, geothermal, and nuclear power are all unsustainable.  Physics SE has covered this exact point before, and we have 10,000s of years to deplete the heat from the mantle.  But depleting the heat from the mantle isn't the end point.  Depleting heat from the reachable layers of the crust is the end point.  Not even that.  You decrease temperature (and efficiency) with use.  You would need full simulation to see the real sustainability of it, and even the unsustainable use is likely to be only *slightly* better than fossil fuels.

Comment: @Zassounotsukushi: The mantle is connected to the core--- you can't deplete the heat from the mantle only. I don't understand your calculation--- it should be in the million years range.

Comment: There is a fundamental limit to the amount of geothermal power that can be generated. The heat flux from the deep Earth is on close order of 44 TW. Add a Carnot efficiency and compare to the current world energy demand...

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare investment in geothermal power and fusion because they're at completely different stages of development. We know how to use geothermal power; after all it's already used in many parts of the world. The problem is that unless you live conveniently near a volcano it's (currently) more expensive than using fossil fuels. Since the engineering issues are well understood, it's not obvious how more investment in research will make it significantly cheaper.

By contrast, no-one has managed to get a fusion reactor to produce more power than it consumes, or at least not for longer than a few moments, and no-one knows whether it will ever be commercially viable. But if it can be made to work its potential is vastly greater than geothermal energy. Unless we do the research we'll never know if fusion will work.

Comment: I don't agree with you on this.  I think Geothermal power is very much in its infancy.  It is not sexy hence why it gets no investment, but surely if we could drill effectively down into the Mantle the power would be limitless?  I say we should spend the money being spent on fusion into drilling techniques / research.  Not very exciting I grant you, but could return our investment a lot sooner...

Comment: As far as I know no-one has advocated drilling into the mantle to extract geothermal power. Not even research drilling has got that far; in fact it hasn't got close. The deepest drill ever, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole, got only a third of the way. Being able to drill into the mantle is even further away than fusion power.

Answer (score 3):

a) [cost of ITER](http://www.iter.org/faq)

> Based on the European evaluation, we can estimate the cost of ITER construction for the seven Members at approximately EUR 13 billion, if built in Europe
>
> ITER is financed by seven Members: China, the European Union (plus Switzerland, as a member of EURATOM), India, Japan, Korea, Russia and the United States. In all, 34 countries are sharing the cost of the ITER project.

So it is not the EU alone that is spending the millions.

Contrast the 13 billion euro to how much an [aircraft carrier cost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimitz_class_aircraft_carrier)s: the US by itself built 10 at a cost of 4.5 billion dollars each, total 45 billion..

So the expense of researching what will be practically a free energy machine of 13 billion shared by 34 countries should be put into perspective.

Now the cost of geothermal wells is [documented](http://www1.eere.energy.gov/geothermal/pdfs/egs_chapter_6.pdf), from a simple search one can have an order of magnitude estimate for the cost of single deep wells, down to 10km. Each well is about 10 to 20 million dollars. The 15 billion of ITER could drill order of magnitude 1000 wells.

That would not cover needs in gigawatts, imo, which are the world needs.

> [According to studies](http://www.geo-energy.org/reports/geo101_final_feb_15.pdf), an economically competitive geothermal power plant can cost as low as  $3400 per kilowatt installed

Geothermal is an interesting parallel source of power, where ever it can be extracted, but cannot beat fusion.

Comment: You are not comparing apples with apples.  The ITER 13 billion will produce 0 watts of commercial power.  So, lets use the 13 billion to research drilling technology only - not very sexy, but could provide a breakthrough to make geothermal workable?

Comment: There are some research articles on laser earth boring?  Could this be the way forward?

Comment: @MattLuckham The technology of well drilling is advanced and detailed in the links I gave.One does not need research on that.I would expect laser technology to be more expensive than standard technology.

Comment: Anna - as we can only drill a fraction in the earths crust at present I would say some research may be useful. I think there are many precedents of scientists thinking we cannot learn anything more in an area only to be proven wrong.  If we can put a man on the moon then surely we can drill a hole 30 miles deep?

Comment: @Matt read a bit the link about drilling and its difficulties. I would not call research something that is engineering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its time to scrap the whole idea, but definitely it is time to devote more resources to alternative approaches. Out of the top of my mind there are two non-mainstream approaches worth pursuing:

[**Focus fusion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_plasma_focus): or as some like to call it, 'spark-plug fusion' because its basically huge spark plugs generating strong magnetic fields during the corona discharge period, they also expect to minimise X ray emission by some clever manipulation of the magnetic field, but i don't get the fine details

[**Polywell fusion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polywell): this is another approach trying to keep a virtual electron anode in the center of a structure of geometrically aligned magnetic toroids that try to minimise the electron leakage rate by tweaking their circulation pattern around the toroids

Comment: I hate downvoting people I agree with, but the reality is that you didn't really address the question.

Answer (score 0):

If by fusion you mean *hot* fusion, the kind done in Tokamaks, then yes, we should forget it. This is a terrible waste of money--- the designs are not going to produce a power plant in 2050 or 2080 or 2100, or 3000, or anytime. It was a good idea, it just didn't pan out, and the scientists involved are constantly afraid of losing their funding, something which should have happened a long time ago. The major issue is that you don't get factors of 100 in efficiency from scaling up, so if the current billion-dollar projects do not produce usable levels of power already (and they don't), scaling them up is not going to produce a realistically competitive power source.

Different ideas for hot fusion, like inertial confinement, are promising. Although they are no closer to a power-plant today, they haven't been explored as well. The only scalable fusion we have today is the H-bomb. There once was a proposal for generating fusion energy by exploding hydrogen bombs in a gigantic underground enclosure. Even considering the enormous size of the enclosure, this would probably be cheaper and easier to make work than a Tokamak. Of course, the security danger of using hydrogen bombs in day-to-day activities probably rules this idea out.

Geothermal energy is very similar to extracting the heat from an underground nuclear explosion. It is a potentially limitless source of energy, and it will not require an open-ended neverending research program.

In this context, one must always mention the great work of Pons and Fleischmann on *cold* fusion, which is completely separate. This is a set of different research directions and ideas, and it makes all this hot fusion nonsense moot. It is clear from Pons and Fleischmann's seminal, era-defining work, that it is possible to use atomic scale chemistry to get fusion. This is where the hot fusion money should have been diverted back in 1989, and some speculate that the prospect of losing money led the hot-fusion scientists to suppress Pons and Fleischmann's work.

Comment: I disagree with your view on non-tokomak hot fusion approaches.  The entire point of polywell, z-pinch, field reversal, and all those sorts of things is that they DO scale well and you can get orders of magnitude efficiency gains with only slightly larger machines.  I imagine you'll get attacked on your cold fusion views too, but I won't be the one to do it.

Comment: Ron, has anybody been able to replicate the positive results claimed by Pons & Fleischmann?

Comment: @Michael Luciuk: By now, hundreds of people, so that the result is established with scientific certainty. In 1989, there were successful replications by McKubre (who used a PF setup), by SPAWAR (who electroplated Pd and deuterium together and looked for nuclear stuff), and a handful of other people, including MIT. MIT noticed the Pons Fleischmann anomalous heating, but fudged their data to show no effect when they learned this science was bad politics. The positive experiments now include transmutation, and gas-loading, and are summarized on lenr-canr.org, so I won't repeat what's there.

Comment: @Zassounotsukushi: I didn't mean to sound critical of non-Tokamak hot fusion--- I think there are promising ideas there. I'll make the wording clearer. As for cold-fusion, I cannot understand the opposition among people who haven't read the literature.

Comment: Sorry to down vote , Ron, but you are off on the Pons et al cold fusion. All physicists were very excited when it broke back then and we all spent time thinking about it. The reason I stopped supporting it is that the energy output is of the order of chemical energies, energies that were spent to make the palladium crystals and are released in their experiment. There is some hope in the recent Low energy Nuclear Reactions, LENR, which they try to separate from the word "fusion". NASA recently went out of the closet on this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBlKc0TaqPs

Comment: @anna v: You are free to downvote, but you are wrong. The word "LENR" is just a code-word for cold-fusion which makes it seem possible that this isn't fusion (but it is), and a term which seeks to remove credit from Pons and Fleischmann, which is just deplorable. The link to NASA stuff you give is crackpottery--- it is based on Widom-Larson neutron addition theory, which is just total nonsense. The "LENR" energy is not of the order of chemical energies, it just seems that way superficially. The Pons/Fleischmann energy release is larger than any chemistry in the electrode could hold.

Comment: I was not talking of electrodes, but of bulk. Anyway, there was no conspiracy against them, people were disappointed and that was that. There are various models for LENR utilising crystal properties , but what I have seen do not have fusion of the usual sort, with H or de.

Comment: @anna v: Where in the bulk could this energy possibly be? The bulk is heavy water--- there is no way to store energy in water. Further, there are light-water controls, the energy is released in heavy water compared to light. The electrode is where the chemistry is happening, and the result is nuclear with 100% confidence, even in 1989. The disappointment you recall (I was alive then too) was just the outcome of the political campaign against Pons and Fleischmann by your incompetent, stupid, colleagues. LENR is to cold fusion as open-source is to free-software, its just a political name-change.

Comment: I think I was thinking of some sort of recombination of oxygen and hydrogen from the electrolysis. It is too long ago. At the time a lot of people were trying to reproduce the results unsuccessfully. I think you are overestimating the importance of criticism  on what by now, 20 years later, should have been a working device.  I am open to the possibility of new ways of tapping energy, even this Rossi/, Defkalion thing: if it works, it works, the theory will follow.Calling it fusion is the problem for me.

Comment: @RonMaimon, as anna, i don't understand how after 20 years there would not be a single enterprenurial scientist which would have developed this into something easier to replicate; let me remind you that the whole "selling point" of cold fusion is that is cheap to setup, compared to the mainstream approaches. If P&F would had something, and that something were cold fusion, we should be having flying cars by now powered by our garden hoses, don't you think?

Comment: not a fair comparison Ron, people was able to build simple setups back then that probed the physical concepts; there was the volta battery, the faraday cage, simple dynamos. Nothing designed with engineering concerns, just to prove that it can be physically done, and more importantly, that could be reproduced. And they did that very well. What i'm seeing is that all these experiments of cold fusion have not been able to reach the stage when their setups are reproducible enough. It reminds me a bit back on the 1994 when Potklenov claimed gravitational effects from superconductor ceramics,..

Comment: but no one was able to reproduce them, then he claimed that the ceramic had to be cooked in a special way to produce a specific microscopic structure, etc. At the end he got upset/bored/etc. and no one brought the effect/observation ever again. I'm not claiming that these things aren't happening, just that there are trends that are common, and one must ask why they are common

Comment: This has more reproductions than Galvani's stuff on electrical jumping frog's legs. There's a video where McKubre talks about walking around with a pocket full of tritium he made, and thinking "This tritium is so controlled, the government would be all over this lab arresting me for prolifiration if they actually believed any of this". Several scientists claim to have significant but trace amounts of tritium in their labs after running their cells. Where the heck did this tritium come from? If you dismiss cold fusion, there is only one answer: coordinated fraud. But _many_ people saw tritium.